# Calculate mode grouped by a column

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, count, greatest-n-per-group

```
+--------+-------+
| client | price |
+--------+-------+
|     54 |    25 |
|    648 |    35 |
|     54 |    10 |
|    648 |     8 |
|     54 |    25 |
|    648 |    35 |
+--------+-------+
```

Lets say above is how my table schema is set up and I want to calculate the most frequent `price` value per `client` eg.

```
+--------+-------+
| client | price |
+--------+-------+
|     54 |    25 |
|    648 |    35 |
+--------+-------+
```

I'm having a hard time accomplishing this in MySQL. I've done it in PHP like so:

```
$clientPrices = $this->database->select('design', [
    'clientid',
    'price'
]);

$pricesByClients = [];
foreach ($clientPrices as $value) {
    $pricesByClients[$value['clientid']][] = $value['price'];
}

foreach ($pricesByClients as $key => $value) {
    $priceCount = array_count_values($value);
    $mode = array_search(max($priceCount), $priceCount);
    $pricesByClients[$key] = $mode;
}

return $pricesByClients;
```

But, this is slow and I was hoping if I can either make this a bit efficient or do it in SQL.

Edit: It's MySQL 5.* and not 8.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please post the version of MySQL and which DB library you are using (`$this->database`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL has no built-in function that computes the `mode()`.

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select client, price
from (
    select client, price, rank() over(partition by client order by count(*) desc) rn
    from mytable
    group by client, price
) t
where rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, and option is to filter with a `having` clause and a correlated subquery

```
select client, price
from mytable t
group by client, price
having count(*) = (
    select count(*)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.client = t.client
    group by t1.price
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1
)
```

Comment: These answers are perfect. But for future reference for anyone who has the same performance issue, it seems like the PHP code is 3X faster than MySQL for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use row_number() window function:

```
select t.client, t.price
from (
  select client, price,
    row_number() over (partition by client order by count(*) desc) rn
  from tablename
  group by client, price
) t
where t.rn = 1;
```

For previous versions you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct t.client, t.price
from tablename t
where (t.client, t.price) = (
  select client, price
  from tablename
  where client = t.client
  group by client, price
  order by count(*) desc
  limit 1
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tqubmc5YXnuqreveExPNtu/0).